# Why it cannot find getInputStream?

Tags: java, networking, sockets

I have this code:

```
ServerSocket serverSideSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        serverSideSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSideSocket.getInputStream()));
```

And compiler writes me that it cannot find "getInputStream". I do not understand why. In the beginning of my code I do import `java.net.*`.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

Comment: So, reading the documentation has once again gone out of style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling of `accept` returns instance of `Socket` which has required method `getInputStream`.

The code might look like this:

```
ServerSocket serverSideSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket socket = serverSideSocket.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Great tutorial how to work with sockets in java: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This because conceptually a `ServerSocket` doesn't provide a direct connection object that can be used to send and receive data. A `ServerSocket` is a tool that you can use with the `.accept()` method to let it listen on the choosen port and generate a new real connection when a client tries to connect.

That's why you can't get an `InputStream` from a `ServerSocket`. Since many clients can connect to the same server, every client will make the server socket generate a new `Socket` (that is an opened *TCP connection*) that is returned from `.accept()` through which you can send and receive using its `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.